# How to handle updating the app on users devices

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play, updates

So after you first deploy your apk to Google Play and it's all up and running, how do you handle updating your app for your users?

Do you have to do the same process every time

- manually change the version number in the manifest
- export and then upload apk to google play console

Or is there a faster way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no faster way but only one way(till now). Its the way you mentioned in your question:

- manually change the version number in the manifest export
- upload apk to google play console

After this, update process is complete from your part. The rest of the work like showing updates to users and allowing update is handled by play store.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I was hoping for something more like committing to git :D